# angular getting Observable<HttpEvent<any[]>> inside my html from ts file

Tags: html, angular, entity-framework-core, typescript-typings

I have started working on angular again after almost 2 years and i thought i could grasp from my previous knowledge but i am kind of stuck over here and cannot really understand what i can do.
I am using efc for getting data and in services i have the following method

shared-service.ts

`getHotelDetails(val:any){`
`return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'Hotels/GetHotel/',val);`
`}`

In ts i am getting the correct data by using the below code

mycomponent.ts

`hotel$!:Observable<HttpEvent<any[]>>;`

`constructor(private service:SharedService, private _route:ActivatedRoute) {`

`}`

`ngOnInit(): void {`
`var Id = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];`
`this.hotel$ = this.service.getHotelDetails(Id);`
`console.log(this.hotel$);`
`}`

mycomponent.html

I am trying to use the hotel object in html but cannot iterate or find the attributes inside. The api call is giving a json like the below for api:

https://localhost:44372/api/Hotels/GetHotel/1

`{`
`"hotelId": 1,`
`"name": "pizza",`
`"addresses": [],`
`"comments": [],`
`"hotelFoods": []`
`}`

I just need the code in which i can fetch the name  from hotel$ attribute.

I tried ngfor and directly accessing hotel$.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get back from the service is an Observable, you need to subscribe to it in order to access the data. The easiest way to  do this in a html template is to use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

You need something like this:

```
{{ (this.hotel$ | async).hotelId }}
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the answer. not sure why i asked this.. seems such an obvious mistake now. I am facing a issue with jwt now if you know about it please check once: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322313/jwt-auth-with-asp-net-core-to-create-token-and-store-in-http-only-cookies-and-an'